# SQL server 2008 not using index with user defined function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL 2008, I'm trying to use a simple User Defined Function in query, but SQL server doesn't use index and the query is executing very long.
Is there way to tell SQL server that result of function can be used in query as simple number/literal, and it can use index?

For example, three situations:

1) Simple select (using index):

```
SELECT * FROM [ORDERS] WHERE [CarId] = 5
```

2) Select with variable (without using index):

```
DECLARE @five int = 5;
SELECT * FROM [ORDERS] WHERE [CarId] = @five
```

2.1) Select with variable, (using index):

```
DECLARE @five int = 5;
SELECT * FROM [ORDERS] WHERE [CarId] = @five OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

3) Select with user function call in query (without using index)

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.five', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.five;

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.five()
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 5;
END;

SELECT * FROM [ORDERS] WHERE [CarId] = dbo.five()
```

[Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9loNP.png)

3.1) using index, but plan not optimal

```
SELECT * FROM [ORDERS] with (index(IDX_CARID)) WHERE [CarId] = dbo.five()
```

[3.1 Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrhKX.png)

Table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [ORDERS](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [dtBegin] [datetime] NULL,
    [dtEnd] [datetime] NULL,
    [CarID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ORDERS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, 
    FILLFACTOR = 90
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [ORDERS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CARS_ORDERS] FOREIGN KEY([CarID])
REFERENCES [CARS] ([ID])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE [ORDERS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CARS_ORDERS]
GO
```

Code of index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CARID] ON [ORDERS]
(
    [CarID] ASC
)WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
    ONLINE = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, 
    FILLFACTOR = 90
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: And item 2 is absolutely okay to you? But item 3 is not, right?

Comment: Please, provide table creation script.

Comment: My real task is a bit more complicated than this example, I need to use the third option, but in this case, SQL does not use an index and the query runs very long. The second option I gave an example that in this case, I can specify the server to use the value of the variable.

Comment: try to use force index with(index(IDX_CARID))

Comment: How many rows are in this table?

Comment: @IvanStarostin about 30 millions

Answer (score 0):

As you are selecting all the fields and the non clustered index is only CarID in your given example so it will always scan and not seek,
Check your execution plan executing below query :

```
SELECT CarId FROM [ORDERS] WHERE [CarId] = dbo.five()
```

if you want all the other values than you will have to include them too in nonclustered index , you can make a single non clustered index which targets to the required selected columns

Answer (score 0):

1. When you are using a function in your where clause the chances of using index is very  less.
2. Why do you think the 3.1 execution plan is not optimal for the query what is written that is the optimal plan.
   If you observe properly  the index scan has been replaced by seek and the only  problem in the plan is key lookup. The key lookup is popping in the plan as you have * in your query

   ```
   Select * from  table where conditions
   ```

Instead of select * if you use the specific column list then the performance will be optimal only  but still i won't say the key  lookup component will be reduced but it all depends on the requirement of you selects.

Thanks